# How to properly import SVG.js 3.0.x version into a Typescript Create-React-App project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, svg.js

As my problems' topic hasn't been answered in detail in any other thread nor there is no good answer at the official Svg.js web-site I am posting it in a new thread with a detailed specification of the problem.

**1. My dev stack is:**

a.) CRA (create-react-app) - "react-scripts": "3.1.2"

b.) Typescript - "typescript": "3.6.3"

c.) SVG.js - "@svgdotjs/svg.js": "^3.0.13"

**2. What I want to achieve:**

I want to import properly SVG.js in order to use it in my  element with id="drawing" to draw svg shapes inside of the  element.

**3. My problem is:**

If I import my Svg.js library this way:

```
import * as SVG from "@svgdotjs/svg.js";
```

or in this way:

```
import SVG from "@svgdotjs/svg.js/src/svg";
```

Then I can't use SVG later in any way in my project.

Doing this for example doesn't work:

```
let draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140)
let rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: "#f06"})
```

I receive messages about **"could not find declaration file for module @svgdotjs/svg.js/src/svg"** when using the second import which I have shown above

and

when using the first import presented by me above, suddenly Intellij Idea shows the types in the code but does not recognize the SVG() and says **"This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import("@svgdotjs/svg.js")' has no call signatures."**

Either way I can't make it working like it should.

My test code is here:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as SVG from "@svgdotjs/svg.js";
//import SVG from "@svgdotjs/svg.js/src/svg";
import './App.css';
const App: React.FC = () => {
  let draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140)
  let rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: "#f06"})
  return (
    <div className="App">
    SVG.js test :)
      <div id="drawing">
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**4. My question is:**

How to import and use with success **Svg.js** in a **create-react-app** with **typescript**?

Only answers with real solutions and not assumptions welcome.

Best regards!

Comment: where is the @types/svgjs dependency?

Comment: It is in node_modules --> @svgdotjs folder --> svg.js subfolder --> svg.js.d.ts 

And inside there are the newest typings for it which are the same as from https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/master/svg.js.d.ts

Comment: I guess the error is, that you use * - so you import everything as `SVG`. So what you want to call is `SVG.SVG()` and not `SVG()`. There is no default import!

Comment: wouldn't the typings catch an error like this? Did you figure out a way @BartB

Answer (score 0):

I did things more like this

```
import React from 'react';
import * as svgjs from "@svgdotjs/svg.js";
import './App.css';
const App: React.FC = () => {
  let draw = svgjs.SVG().addTo('#drawing').viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140)
  let rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: "#f06"})
  ....
```

But I get excetption at runtime in webpack:///node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/src/elements/Dom.js